# JSON parsing: Unexpected character (ÿ) at position 0

Tags: java, json

as I searched around, it seems that a lot of people have similar problems, but none of those fixes worked for me.
So I'm trying to parse this JSON file with JSON.simple:

http://pastebin.com/ZNCV9Xrz

I already checked if it's valid JSON and it is.

This is the java code I'm working with:

http://pastebin.com/RGNdvwAa

I'm quite new in this area of java and have no idea how to fix this.
I tried lots of different JSON codes, some very short so I figured the problem is in the java code.

Thanks in advance,
T0Bi

Comment: Please put the relevant data and code in the question, not as links.

Comment: What charset is the file written in, and what charset are you trying to read it in?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using UTF8 everywhere? Your system might be using something else as the default encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ÿ` is character 255 in ISO-8859-1 (and maybe other character encodings). It is also the first byte of the Byte Order Marker for UTF16_LE.

Please check the encoding you are using to save the file, and use the appropriate character set when you open it for reading, e.g.

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF16_LE)
```

Comment: When i change the coding of the json file i get a new error, this time its the Unexpected character (ï).  
And how would I integrate your code into mine ?  
 I also get the error that it cant find StandardCharsets.  
And thanks for the fast reply !!

Comment: What did you change - the way you save the file or the way you read the file? StandardCharsets is in Java 7. If you are still on Java 6, you can use `Charset.forName("...")`, but you also have to handle the `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: At first, i changed saving the file, it is now at UTF8.  
I dont know how to change the way to read the file though

Comment: But where would I integrate this ? I'm currently at the level of copypasting stuff and somehow trying to figure it out.  
And i get the error: cannot find symbol - variable  StandardCharset

Comment: Well I don't actually know which JSONParser class you are using - but you can probably pass the `InputStreamReader` above either to the constructor or to the parse method.

Answer (score 1):

You're having encoding issues. The constructor of `FileReader` uses environment specific encoding.

Check what encoding your JSON file uses, then specify it when reading the file:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), ###ENCODING GOES HERE###)
```